# Comparing all elements of 2 lists with Python 2

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I have 2 lists: `a = ['5', '2', '3', '4']`, and `b = ['1', '6', '7', '5']`. Using Python 2, how can I compare each list element in `a` to each element in `b`? (i.e. is `a[0] == b[0]`, is `a[0] == b[1]`, etc).

I know that I could just write out numerous `if` statements, but I hope that there is a more elegant way to do this.

After checking each list element, I want to know how many times a shared value was found (in my example lists above, it would be one time, `'5'`).

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, b/c i am comparing two different lists to each other, while the possible duplicate dealt with only 1 list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus not a duplicate, added explanation

Comment: To those who downvoted this question, what can I do in the future to improve my questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method of `list` may help:

```
>>> a = ['5', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b = ['1', '6', '7', '5']
>>> for item in a:
...     print item, b.count(item)
... 
5 1
2 0
3 0
4 0
```

Comment: It's `O(len(a) * len(b))`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably faster for big inputs than [eugene y's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36115748/3821804), as it only needs to iterate over `b` once,
instead of `len(a)` times:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(b)

for i in a:
    print(i, counts[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with shared values, and not with their positions or counts, convert them to `set` and use [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> a = ['5','2','3','4']
>>> b = ['1','6','7','5']
>>> set(a).intersection(b)
{'5'}
```

If you want to retain how often the elements appear in the intersection, you can also do an intersection of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) using `&`

```
>>> a = ['5','2','3','4','1','1','6','5']
>>> b = ['1','6','7','5','5']
>>> collections.Counter(a) & collections.Counter(b)
Counter({'5': 2, '1': 1, '6': 1})
```

Note: This is different from the solution by @GingerPlusPlus in that it is symmetric, i.e. if `5` is present once in list `a` and twice in list `b`, then the shared count will be `1`, not `2`.

Comment: "I want to know how many times a shared value was found" - sounds like OP want's a count. Intersection wouldn't work if there were two instances of the number `5` in list `b`

Comment: @pyInTheSky That is correct, i want to know if 5 is duplicated twice

Comment: @pyInTheSky Yes, that's one interpretation. But it could also mean the count of distinct shared values. That's why I added the introductory note.

Comment: that's fine, I didn't downvote you at all. Your updated solution is interesting, I had no idea the __and__ operator for Counter had some wonky magic. Pasting the help of the fn here if anyone else is curious as to how your solution works: __and__(self, other) method of collections.Counter instance
    Intersection is the minimum of corresponding counts.
    
    >>> Counter('abbb') & Counter('bcc')
    Counter({'b': 1})

Answer (score 0):

```
def cmp(*lists):
    lists_len_min = list(map(lambda x: len(x), lists))
    if min(lists_len_min) != max(lists_len_min):
        raise Exception("Lists must have equal length")
    iterator = iter(lists)
    last = next(iterator)
    for element in iterator:
        for i, each in enumerate(element):
            #print(i, last[i], each)
            if last[i] != each:
                return False
    else:
        return True
```

This function can compare as many lists you want with equal length. Just call cmp(list1, list2, list3)

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce list of elements which is consist in both `a` and `b` list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,1,7]
c = [e for e in a if e in b]
```

It might be complex by memory in case if you use big arrays but if you plan to use this data than why not